# Build several artifact with maven classifier plugin vs. modules

Tags: maven, module, classification

Here is the context : one application, let's name it "clientdata" is bundle into an ear to be deploy on WebSphere. We need to generate several jar for this application :

- api-contract (interfaces)
- ejb
- ejb-client
- impl

The ear contains ejb, impl and api-contract jar + the application dependencies

Let's call "checkclient" another application which need to call "clientdata" by RMI.
It will need to use api-contract and ejb-client jar.

For now the application is divided into 3 sub-modules (API, IMPL and EJB).

API module generate api-contract jar

IMPL module generate impl jar and use api-contract jar

EJB module generate ejb and ejb-client and use impl and api-contract jar

So here is my question : one member of the team thinks that we should use maven classifier plugin to generate all those jar so that we need but to maintain only one pom (one maven project).

I'm not so familiar with maven classifier plugin so i wanted to know, is this a good idea ?
Some of my readings make me think it is not, mostly because it violate a "core convention" and "Tools that have been designed to work with Maven won’t help you"

Here is the source of the citations : http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.U7UhNCgucvQ

I would greatly appreciate your expertise on the subject.

Regards, GBE.

Answer (score 2):

First the member of your team is simply wrong, cause that's the wrong way to deal with such default scenario in Maven. I assume (hope) you have created an appropriate folder structure

```
  +-- root (pom.xml)
       +-- mod-api (pom.xml)
       +-- mod-ejb (pom.xml)
       +-- mod-impl (pom.xml)
       +-- mod-ear (pom.xml)
```

Based on the above folder structure you can simply define dependencies between the modules and let maven do the rest. Apart from that you can create the [ejb-client automatically by maven-ejb-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/generating-ejb-client.html) and use this for furthere enhancements.

Now you can create an ear from it (mod-ear just add the dependencies to it) and just deploy it to WebSphere. That the way it should go. Creating a single pom to create that number of artifacts is by definition against the desing of Maven cause the convention in Maven is to have a single pom for an artifact. So you will start to fight against Maven and you will loose that combat.
Better got with the idea of Maven and make your life easier. Apart from that it's a separation of concern which means an single pom for a single part of the project which makes it clear where you can find anything in your project. Here is a [simple example of a Java EE application](https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee).

Comment: You assumed right for the folder structure of the application. However, I'm trying to find pros/cons arguments and I can't find any except "This is the way Maven encourage you to do it" ?
Let's assume I create 2 modules : 1 to generate API, IMPL and EJB and another one to create an EAR. API / IMPL and EJB don't share any classes, but we would manage the code inside one and only one module, this way we would have only one pom to maintain (it would generate the differents artifacts)
What problems would arise from such organization ?